# react-ga4 (Google Analytics) events are not consistent

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am finding some very inconsistent results while using the npm package `react-ga4`.

```
const TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent = (name, category, action, label, value) => {
  // Send GA4 Event
  ReactGA.event(name, {
    category: category,
    action: action,
    label: label,
    value: value,
  });
};
```

Initially I thought the issue was that some of my events are being called in `<a>` tags.

```
          <a

            href="/what-we-do"
            onClick={() =>
              TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(
                "header_services_click",
                "button",
                "click"
              )
            }
          >
            Services
          </a>
```

However I noticed that even normal button clicks are not always being tracked.

```
            <ButtonWhiteFixed
              buttonText="Get Started Today"
              onClick={() => {
                TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(
                  "home_get_started_today_click",
                  "button",
                  "click"
                );
                navigate("/contact");
              }}
              type="button"
              size="lg"
            />
```

I am not sure if GA4 is just buggy or if something in my implementation is off.

I am calling my initialization in my index.js. So this runs on every page render, but that is the way most articles describe the setup.

Comment: category, action, label and value are your custom dimensions? then explain how you have created them and how you have created the relationship between these custom dimensions to your Event? are you using GTM?